# Adding all elements in array to linked list in order

Tags: java

This is  my code. Why am I getting an Unsupported Operation exception. I searched out some threads saying how you need to change the array as a list and then add. Is this correct for my instructions as well?

```
public class DLinkedList<E> extends AbstractList<E> {

    /** Reference to the first node in our linked list. This will be null if the list is empty. */
    private Entry head;

    /** Reference to the last node in our linked list. This will be null if the list is empty. */
    private Entry tail;

    /** Number of elements currently in the list. */
    private int size;

    /**
     * Creates an empty list.
     */
    public DLinkedList() {
        DLinkedList<E>retVal= null;
        size = 0;
        head = null;
        tail = null;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new linked list and initializes it so that it stores the elements from the given array in the identical
     * order.
     *
     * @param source Array holding the elements that should be stored in our new linked list.
     */


    public DLinkedList(E[] source) {
        DLinkedList<E>retVal= new  DLinkedList<E>();
        int l=source.length;
        for(int i=0;i<l;i++) {

            retVal.add(source[i]);


        }

    }
```

Comment: I'm confused. This is a constructor, that now has a local variable `retVal` that it doesn't (and cannot) return? Or it is creating an instance of itself (DLinkedList) (that may not have a `.add(...)` method)?

Comment: is DLinkedList  a class you made? can you copy the code?, and either that method is missing its name or it is the class constructor, in which case you shouldn't create another object of itself there

Comment: I just  pasted the whole code

Answer (score 1):

The `AbstractList` class provides *dummy* methods for many of the list operations.  The dummy methods typically throw `UnsupportedOperationException` if called.  You need to *override* the inherited `add` method in your `DLinkedList` class.

Read the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html) for `AbstractList`.

---

Also, there are other problems with your constructors:

- You should not have those local `retval` variables.
- You should be operating on `this`.
- Your 2nd constructor should probably be using a `this()` call to chain to the first constructor.

Please review your lecture notes / tutorial material / textbook on Java constructors and constructor chaining.